# How to delay jQuery Waypoint for each item in order to create staggering effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-waypoints

I am trying to delay waypoint for every next item by 0.2s. I tried with set timeout but by the time the first few items load the timeout has already expired.

[Fiddle 1](http://jsfiddle.net/bwtq71f8/)

```
$(function() {

  $(".item").each(function(index, element) {
    var $this = $(this);

    var $delay = $(this).data('delay');
    setTimeout(function() {

      $this.waypoint(function() {

        $(this.element).addClass('show');

      }, {
        offset: '90%',
      });

    }, $delay);


  });

});
```

Than I tried adding the delays inside the waypoint but the last items get longer delays since they are not in the view

```
$(function() {

  $(".item").each(function(index, el) {

    new Waypoint({
      element: el,
      handler: function() {
        var element = $(this.element),
          delay = element.attr('data-delay');
        setTimeout(function() {
          element.addClass('show');
        }, delay);
        this.destroy();
      },
      offset: '90%'
    });

  });

});
```

[Fiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/04pk95q8/1/)

any help is appreciated.

Comment: Unless I'm missing what you're trying to do, Fiddle 1 works perfectly for me (in Chrome 48.0.2564.116 m)

Comment: @Ageonix , works ok for the first items in view , when you scroll the rest of them appear without the delay, they just fade in, instead each to wait 0.2s and than fade in

Comment: @PapaSmurf, no bud , each item must delay by 0.2s once in view

Comment: Ah I see what you mean now.  I doubled the amount of DIV's you have in the Fiddle and it made it easier to see the issue.

Comment: Ok, the `handler` function is called immediately, if you run the script and immediately scroll down the page you can see that last item was showed after 1600ms.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to create this staggered effect without knowing how many items will be in view and trying to do all the acrobatics described in other answers and comments, you can instead use the waypoint to feed a queue and process items in that queue at your staggered interval. This is true in general, not just for animation and not just for Waypoints.

```
$(function() {
  var itemQueue = []
  var delay = 200
  var queueTimer

  function processItemQueue () {
    if (queueTimer) return // We're already processing the queue
    queueTimer = window.setInterval(function () {
      if (itemQueue.length) {
        $(itemQueue.shift()).addClass('show');
        processItemQueue()
      } else {
        window.clearInterval(queueTimer)
        queueTimer = null
      }
    }, delay)
  }

  $(".item").waypoint(function () {
    itemQueue.push(this.element)
    processItemQueue()
  }, {
    offset: '90%'
  })
})
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/imakewebthings/416dfzmx/2/)

Comment: Thanks for the solutioin but unfortunately it does not work 100% as expected. The delay for the first item that enters the browser viewport is always 200 but it should be 0. Any chance you can help to solve this?

Comment: Thanks for this. I have noticed that if I use a few of those functions for different elements, the order in which they pop up changes. Any idea why would that happen?

Answer (score 1):

The second fiddle you have will work BUT you have to take a few things into account:

1. How many items will be visible immediately when the browser loads? These items will need to have delays that are 200ms apart (e.g. 200, 400, 600, 800).
2. Any additional items that will only be visible upon scrolling will need to start back at 200ms in terms of scroll delay. Take for example your jsfiddle where as you scroll through 2 new item Waypoints are triggered at a time. These will need to again be 200ms apart (200, 400, 200, 400, etc.). In other words, each 'row' needs to start back at 200ms and increment by 200 until it reaches the end of the row.

   ```
   <div id="container">
     <div class="item" data-delay="200">
       <div class="item-in"></div>
     </div>
     <div class="item" data-delay="400">
       <div class="item-in"></div>
     </div>
     <div class="item" data-delay="600">
       <div class="item-in"></div>
     </div>
     <div class="item" data-delay="800">
       <div class="item-in"></div>
     </div>
     <div class="item" data-delay="200">
       <div class="item-in"></div>
     </div>
     <div class="item" data-delay="400">
       <div class="item-in"></div>
     </div>
     <div class="item" data-delay="200">
       <div class="item-in"></div>
     </div>
     <div class="item" data-delay="400">
       <div class="item-in"></div>
     </div>
   </div>
   ```

[See this adaptation of your second fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/04pk95q8/4/).

Comment: Well , I was thinking about exactly that , problem is that the items are used inside isotope , so I have no rows , they are all in 1 row and I have no idea how to determine how many of them are going to be visible and when the new timeouts should start.

Comment: here , this is example of what I see in your fiddle , http://prntscr.com/aaoe8n , so that is bigger issue than the one I already have. But thnx for trying!

Comment: @Benn I'm not familiar with isotope but for this to work you are going to need to either control the formatting of the items or dynamically determine how many rows and columns there are and again how many are initially visible when the document loads. I can't imagine there is no way to define a predetermined number of rows?

Comment: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout-modes/masonry.html that is isotope, you cant determine , isotope is flexible and adapts to user screen. each item is also flexible, so I cant hunt the browsers, screen sizes , etc in order to do this right.